# Null instead of integer foreign key performance and space considerations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that has 18 million rows, and I found out today that I don't really need to know one of the foreign key columns depending on another column value.

My question is.

- If I set that column to NULL instead of a foreign integer key that I really don't need, will this save space?
- Is there any performance considerations if I set the foreign key to null on the row. Is it going to speed up the query or slow it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the fixed-width data-types are stored always. The only difference between the `NULL` and not-`NULL` state is whether the corresponding bit is set in the null bitmap. Presumably, this is to speed up interpreting the data-structure at query time. Fixed-offset column values help with read and write access.

With `ROW` or `PAGE` compression, though, you will realize the savings (assuming that compression did not already shrink the column down considerably).

To answer the 2nd point, there is not enough information here to do that. Depends on the queries being run.